# how to install apache,mysql,php as non root without using apt-get?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, lamp

I am using ubuntu 13.04 version.I am newbie for ubuntu.Can i able to install LAMP as non-root and without using sudo apt-get?

Comment: Using Windows, of course!

Comment: have you looked at the taskel option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your system has the resources to accommodate a virtual machine, you could try a much cleaner approach. You can install a pre-made lamp stack from [bitnami](http://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) or [turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack). This approach is cleaner because your host system is left unaffected. Plus you get to play - if you like - with a bunch of different technologies like connecting to and managing a remote server (either through the web interface or via command line), configuring networks, setting-up/modifying ssl settings, etc. You can explore at your heart's content and it's a great learning experience.

Edit: Just to make things clear. Both bitnami and turnkey offer native installers for a wide range of operating systems. This option installs a full blown stack on your machine. What I am referring to in my answer is the virtual machine option. In this case you will download a ready-made virtual machine and run it with vmware (free player) or VirtualBox (free). This option is what I refer to as "clean" because it is completely autonomous from your host system and portable (you can copy the virtual machine files to another host at any time with no need to reconfigure anything)

Comment: Thankyou. I downloaded bitnami-lampstack-5.4.15-0-linux-installer.run. But i couldn't able to install it.can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: You have downloaded the installer. To install this you need to make it executable. Open a terminal and type chmod +x bitnami-lampstack-5.4.15-0-linux-installer.run then ./bitnami-.... to run it. This will install the lamp stack on your machine. In my answer I was referring to the virtual machine, which comes as a zip file and contains a .iso image that you can install on a virtual machine like virtualbox or vmware.

Comment: A correction to my above comment: the .zip file contains a .vmdk file which is a ready made virtual machine disk that you need to attach to a (new) virtual machine. Check the instructions - with screenshots - here: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_start_your_BitNami_Virtual_Appliance.3f

Answer (score 0):

You can run a standalone version of Apache/MySQL/PHP and Perl using [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). Which means you don't need to use `apt-get` to install anything. However since it listens for incoming requests on privileged ports you need to start it using `sudo`. I can't see any way around running it without sudo privileges. If you don't have root on the box in question, which I'm presuming you don't, then why don't you ask the admin to give you `sudo` for the start/stop xampp commands or install the stack for you?

Comment: so what you are saying is that you can download it and start it but you can't use it unless you are `sudo`. And if you are `sudo` why not use apt-get to begin with?

Comment: @Alvar, that is what I'm saying yes. I was just in the process of updating my answer to cover that a little better :)

Comment: @AJefferiss You can't install/uninstall nothing in Ubuntu, without being asked about password or without being root.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu xampp isn't technically installed, it's a statically linked version of a lampp stack. So you can just drop it into a directory under ~/. What you can't do with xampp is start it on privileged ports without sudo

Comment: @AJefferiss Because when you start it will *install* something not under your home directori

Comment: @RaduRădeanu what does it install? It's my understanding that it creates a instance of Apache that has a document root of ~/lampp/htdocs (presuming you extracted the tar.gz to ~/). To get rid of it completely all you need to do is delete that directory...

Comment: @AJefferiss In linux "everything is a file", even if is a instance or a process and this should be placed/installed somewhere. This was what I meant.